# Jquery/Javascript PDF editor

Tags: jquery, pdf-generation

Looking for PDF editor where we can Combine, Split, Extraction, Remove, Rotation, Add Bookmark, Move Pages,  Property & Display settings with drag & drop files?

Is there any opensource available?

Comment: Have you got any solution yet?

Comment: @rahim.nagori Have a look at this.
https://github.com/ShizukuIchi/pdf-editor